# php search box results display incorrectly?

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to make a php search box using the following code but when i press submit, it displays all three entries in wallname instead of the one that is relative to the search.

php:

```php
if (isset($_POST['submit-search'])){
    $searchq= $_POST['search-input'];
    $query = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT wallname FROM walldb WHERE 
       wallname LIKE '%$searchq%'");
    $result= mysqli_num_rows($query);
    if ($result = 0){
      echo "error search";
    } else{
      while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)){
          $name = $row['wallname'];
          $output = '<div>'.$name.'</div>';
          print ("$output");
      }
    }
}
```

html:

```
 <form action= "" method= "post">
        <button type= "submit" name="submit-search">Search</button>
        <input id="search" name="search-input" type="text" placeholder="Search By Name" 
        autocomplete="off"><a href="#"><img id="cancle" src="/images/cancle.png"></a>
 </form>
```

result after typing something in the search box and pressing search :

```
win7-haystack
win10-iceland
win10-road
```

Comment: btw, What was the value of Searchq?

If you want to have the exact match omit % symbols in the search query or use where wallname="{$searchq}".

Comment: i tried haystack, iceland and road but it still shows the same result

Comment: You are all open to SQL Injections. This code is unsafe to run. Rewrite the line with the post variable so it is like this: $myvar = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["whatever"]);

Comment: oh, yes forgot about that. thankyou!
still does not work tho :(

Comment: This is because you are trying to display the output inside a while loop. There could be three possible output throwing by the query and thus while loop display three answers

Comment: Also another side note i would like to highlight is `if ($result = 0){` this part. It should be `if ($result == 0){`.

Comment: can you help with the right way to code it?

Comment: @OscarSortlandKolsrud That's still SQL injection. Use prepared statements with placeholder values. It's the only way to be sure.

Comment: **WARNING**: When using `mysqli` you should be using [parameterized queries](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and [`bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to add any data to your query. **DO NOT** use string interpolation or concatenation to accomplish this because you have created a severe [SQL injection bug](http://bobby-tables.com/). **NEVER** put `$_POST`, `$_GET` or data *of any kind* directly into a query, it can be very harmful if someone seeks to exploit your mistake.

Comment: Note: The [object-oriented interface to `mysqli`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.connections.php) is significantly less verbose, making code easier to read and audit, and is not easily confused with the obsolete `mysql_query` interface where missing a single `i` can cause trouble. Example: `$db = new mysqli(…)` and `$db->prepare("…")` The procedural interface is largely an artifact from the PHP 4 era when `mysqli` API was introduced and should not be used in new code.

Comment: If you're just getting started with PHP and want to build applications, I'd strongly recommend looking at various [development frameworks](https://www.cloudways.com/blog/best-php-frameworks/) to see if you can find one that fits your style and needs. They come in various flavors from lightweight like [Fat-Free Framework](https://fatfreeframework.com/) to far more comprehensive like [Laravel](http://laravel.com/). These give you concrete examples to work from and guidance on how to write your code and organize your project's files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since there are a lot of comments about using prepared statements and PDO, a solution using PDO is given below:

> Read more about PDO [here](https://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-mysql.php)

```php
$dsn = "mysql:host=YOUR_MYSQL_HOST;dbname=YOUR_DATABASE_NAME;charset=utf8mb4";
$options = [
  PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES   => false, // turn off emulation mode for "real" prepared statements
  PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE            => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION, //turn on errors in the form of exceptions
  PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE => PDO::FETCH_ASSOC, //make the default fetch be an associative array
];
try {
  $pdo = new PDO($dsn, "username", "password", $options);
} catch (Exception $e) {
  error_log($e->getMessage());
  exit('Could not connect to the database.');
}
```

```php
$arr = [];
$searchq = "%{$_POST['search-input']}%";
$stmt = $pdo->prepare("SELECT wallname FROM walldb WHERE wallname LIKE ?");
$stmt->execute([$searchq]);
while ($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
  $arr[] = $row;
}
if(!$arr) exit('No results found');

print_r($arr);
```

> For extra reading: [An article](https://websitebeaver.com/php-pdo-prepared-statements-to-prevent-sql-injection) about preventing SQL injection using PDO

Comment: this gives me an array of all the values on page reload, searching anything is not working at all for me for some reason

Comment: i got it to work! it was a conflicting javascript. thanks for the informative answer :)